# How to get ip address & email id in OnException() - method mvc 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am logging all Exceptions to database, overridden onException() in controller.

The Following is the code sample.

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            // this is controller level exception handling.
            var exceptionSource = StandardCodes.ControllerLevel;
            var controllerName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]+".cs";
            var actionName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
        }
```

I need capture user email-id and IP Address to log to database. How get these values in this method ?

Comment: How is Email ID stored for user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To log IP address use HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress

I am not sure what you are using for Email-ID. If you are using User Identity, then you can get HttpContext.User